# Error creating object factory in TestNG

Tags: ant, testng, objectfactory

I have a problem with TestNG. When I run tests in Eclipse everything it's OK, but when I run test in ANT i get errors:

```
    TEST-RUN:
       [testng] [TestNG] [Error] 
       [testng] Error creating object factory: class SomeClassTest
       [testng] The tests failed.
```

In test I use:

```
    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the 'objectFactory' attribute in the testng ant task, something like `objectFactory="org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory"`. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-dev/h68SIRxbeNI for more information. Hope that helps?